# AFCI keeps tripping

Tags: electrical

When I run a Dyson Fan, a TV, and a power strip (*that powers my computer, monitor, cable box, and printer*) off of one circuit with an AFCI in the house it trips.

If I move the power strip (*and all electronics attached to it*) to a different circuit, then it doesn't trip.

If I remove the computer from the power strip and plug it directly into the AFCI circuit, the system still works.

Is it the power strip?  Or the combination of the computer, monitor, cable box, and printer all attached to the power strip that's causing the issue?

Comment: you can answer your own questions by simply removing various combinations of devices from the power strip ... determine which combination causes the issue

Comment: You can report AFCI nuisance tripping at https://www.afcisafety.org/home-owners/unwanted-tripping/
Not that they care, but you can report it.

Comment: What make/model are your AFCIs? Have you tried systematically working through appliance combinations to see which appliance or combination of appliances triggers the trip?

Comment: I'd say continue the troubleshooting, but move *one load at a time* over to the other circuit.  The PC first, since losing power for it sucks... but then after a testing period, leave the PC on, and move over one other thing at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You should try moving both the power strip and the fan.

The fan is actually the most likely *primary* culprit. However, it may trigger the AFCI only when the other stuff is plugged in (e.g. increasing the load on the circuit, and thus changing the way the breaker responds).

People don't usually use plasma displays for their PC monitors, but that's another type of device that is know for generating false-positive trips on AFCI breakers.

As far as resolving the issue, that's a much harder issue, other than doing what you've already done (moving things to different circuits). I have been struggling with this same sort of thing in my new home, which has AFCI or AFCI/GFCI combos on almost all of the circuits. In many cases, the AFCI breaker has turned out to be defective. Replacing it fixes the problem. I have two appliances that seem to trigger an AFCI breaker most easily: a Dyson vacuum cleaner, and a Breville toaster oven.

The vacuum cleaner is less surprising. Cheaper electric motors with brushes generate electrical arcs naturally as part of their operation, and these can be incorrectly detected as a fault by the AFCI breaker. The toaster oven is a little more surprising, but it does use some type of switching power supply internally that might generate a radio signal of the right sort to confuse the breaker, due to the way it's modulated to maintain a set temperature in the oven.

One last thing to try is to find a power strip with an RF filter built into it. This is usually a documented feature; if the power strip doesn't mention it, it probably doesn't have it. The RF filter can in some cases filter out the signal that is triggering the breaker. (Keeping in mind that with such power strips, you won't be able to use a powerline network extender, since it also filters out the signals that uses; this is not commonly found though, and since you didn't mention using one, I'm assuming it doesn't apply in your case.)